# Azure soft limits and ARM resources

Tags: powershell, azure, administration, azure-cli

azure has a set of default soft limits for every subscription (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/)

While I could easily check the current VM cores limit in *ASM* (via the old portal), I've not been able to determine what these limits are for *ARM* only subscriptions (ARM resources are not listed in the old portal and there is no way to check limits on the new portal).

Is there a way (Powershell, CLI or API call) to check cores limit for ARM-only subscriptions ?

Comment: On the new portal, if you click **Subscription**, choose the subscription you wan to view, click **Settings**, and then click **Usage + quotas**, you will see a blade telling you that it is not available yet. I am still looking for some other way to do this.

Comment: Cool thanks. This link redirects to the old portal and does not report ARM resources. Any chance you have a magic way to get actual ARM consumption ? (like: I have a subscription with an armada of ARM VM's and the quota page reports "0" used cores...)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible via Azure CLI, too:

```
~ $ azure config mode arm
info:    Executing command config mode
info:    New mode is arm
info:    config mode command OK

~ $ azure vm list-usage --location eastus
info:    Executing command vm list-usage
data:    Name                         Unit   CurrentValue  Limit
data:    ---------------------------  -----  ------------  -----
data:    Availability Sets            Count  16            2000 
data:    Total Regional Cores         Count  174           350  
data:    Virtual Machines             Count  58            10000
data:    Virtual Machine Scale Sets   Count  0             50   
data:    Standard A0-A7 Family Cores  Count  122           350  
data:    Basic A Family Cores         Count  4             350  
data:    Standard DS Family Cores     Count  48            350  
info:    vm list-usage command OK
```

This command simply does not work in ASM mode. Sounds accurate.

Comment: If you need json output to ingest that into another process, just add "--json" to the list-usage command.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PowerShell cmdlet **Get-AzureRmVMUsage** to see how many cores you have provisioned and what your limit is.  Note that this cmdlet takes a mandatory Location parameter, because with ARM, you can have different limits for each resource type in each region.